# How do you update rust's tonic service

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

Consider the following code (w.o boilerplate):

```rust
use tonic::transport::Server;

Server::builder()
        .add_service(MyServer::new(my_service))
        .serve(addr)
        .await?;
```

So now `my_service` is running on the tonic `MyServer` and all is well.
During runtime the user changed the config file and issued a SIGHUP to tell the service to update.

The problem is that ownership of `my_service` has bee taken out of my hands into the tonic `Router`. So do I need some fancy use of `RC` or `RefCell` to update the service? Or maybe there is an easier way of doing it?

Maybe there is a better framework than `tonic` that works well with protobuf?

This is my first time coding rust I must say...

Comment: Can a similar approach help? https://gist.github.com/snoyberg/54df3cc7fa1ee1fa77cbde6c75f3df0c#file-main-rs-L79